# INItemStats vs INSiteStatus vs INLocationStatus

Tags: acumatica

As per subject. What's the difference between these three tables ? Essentially, I'm looking for the QtyOnHand of an item. And these tables the have QtyOnHand field with the same data. INSiteStatus table seems to be quantity on the warehouses(Sites).

Comment: depends on at what level you need. By warehouse? by location? by lot/serial number (INLotSerialStatus)? @Hybridzz pointed out the differences. If you need by warehouse then i would just use INSiteStatus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the differences i noticed.

INItemStatus:
Quantity details of an item in warehouses

INSiteStatus:
Quantity details of an item and its subitem in warehouses

INLocationStatus:
Quantity details of an item and its subitem in locations of warehouses

[image]